# Display multiple lists in C#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have a list of products, and the list will dynamically grow as more users add to it. I would like to have this list, say:

```
public class Product()
{
   public int ProductId { get; set; } 
   public string ProductName { get; set; } 
   public DateTime ProductDateCreated{ get; set; }
   //....
}
```

But, for every, say, five items listed, I want to display another item from a different list, so say my Advert list.

```
public class Advert()
{
   public int AdvertId { get; set; } 
   public string AdvertName { get; set; } 
   public int AdvertView{ get; set; } 
}

var products = db.Products.OrderBy(d=>d.ProductDateCreated).ToList();

--product1
--product2
--product3
--product4
--Advert2   <-- Insert here some how as it has a higher AdvertView than Advert1
--product5
--product6
--product7
--product8
--product9
--Advert1    <-- Insert here some how as it has a lower AdvertView than Advert2
```

The best way I can describe this is like adverts on Facebook where, as you scroll down, you are presented with adverts now and again.

I use [lambda expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) querying my database, but I cannot think where to start with this.

Comment: When will u decide to display elements from the first List? is it gonna be done periodically ?

Comment: Side comment: When defining a class, you don't use parenthesis next to the class name.

Comment: You could add to a `List<object>` and then parse on the way out I guess..

Comment: Unless Product and Advert share an interface or a base class, you will only able to populate a `List<object>` with instances of both classes. Since this seems to be a question about presentation, why not have a list of each kind and let the presentation layer play with both lists?

Comment: If you will show data on a web page, why don't you use dynamic ajax requests? You can set the number of products to a hidden element, and request an Advert item after every and each 5 product is loaded. Otherwise, you need to use loop since it seems to me impossible to do that in a single lambda expression.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a base class that contains properties, which exist in both classes (name, id,..?):

```
public class Product: Items
{      
    public DateTime ProductDateCreated { get; set; }
    //....
}

public class Advert: Items
{

    public int AdvertView { get; set; }
}

public class Items //Advert and Products
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And fill it as you asked with Advert every 5th item.

```
List<Advert> adverts = db.Adverts.OrderByDescending(a => a.AdvertView).ToList();
List<Product> products = db.Products.OrderBy(d => d.ProductDateCreated).ToList();
List<Items> ResultList = new List<Items>();
for (int i = 0; i < products.Count; i++)
{
    ResultList.Add(products[i]);
    if ((i + 1) % 5 == 0)
    {
        int advertsIndex = i / 5;
        if (adverts.Count + 1 >= advertsIndex)
            ResultList.Add(adverts[advertsIndex]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Select products page by page, and add the products in the page to a base list. After that, pick an Advert from DB and add it to the same base list.

```
List<object> allItems = new List<object>();
int numOfProdPerPage = 5;
int n = ... // number of products to be listed

var products = db.Products.OrderBy(d=>d.ProductDateCreated);
var adverts = db.Adverts.OrderByDescending(d=>d.AdvertView);

for(int p = 0; p< n / numOfProdPerPage ; p++)
{
    var productsPerPage = products.Skip(numOfProdPerPage * p)
                                  .Take(numOfProdPerPage ).ToList();

    allItems.AddRange(products);

    Advert advert = adverts.ElementAt<Advert>(p);

    allItems.Add(advert);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't show how to display the adverts by AdvertView, though

Comment: Just to simplify the solution, I didn't add how to select desired Advert. Now, it would take the highest one I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

1. Sort your adverts list by "AdvertView" descending
2. After you display 5 products, show the next advert from the list
3. If there are more than 5 * advert.Count products, start over in your advert list.

In the example I am just showing Product Name and Advert Name. Ideally you would overwrite `ToString()` so they display themselves properly, but your question seemed to be about how to order the Adverts and display them after every five products.

Sample code:

```
var products = db.Products.OrderBy(d => d.ProductDateCreated).ToList();
var adverts = db.Adverts.OrderByDescending(a => a.AdvertView).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < products.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(products[i].ProductName);

    if ((i + 1) % 5 == 0) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(adverts[(i / 5) % adverts.Count].AdvertName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Somewhere in your code you surely have a function that renders the list to HTML, insert a counter variable and keep track of how many items where displayed already. if you encounter the fifth item, place a new Advert there.

```
void RenderToHTML(List<Product> Products)
{
  int AdvertCounter = 0;
  foreach (Product product in Products)
  {
    if (AdvertCounter == 5)
    {
      Advertcounter = 0;
      AddAdvertToList(); //implement somewhere else
    }
    Advertcounter++;
    AddProduct(product); //implement somwhere else too
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't show how to display the adverts starting with the hightest AdvertView

Answer (score -1):

Try to use something like this:

```
 List<Product> list1;
 List<Advert> list2 ;

 //Full list1 && list 2
 int counterForList2 = 0;
 foreach (string value in list1)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(value);
     if (list1.Count() % 5 == 0)
     {
         if (counterForList2 == list2.Count)
             counterForList2 = 0;
         Console.WriteLine(list2[counterForList2]);
         counterForList2++;
     }
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't show how to display the adverts by AdvertView, though

Answer (score -1):

Your question assumes design solution, which, in my opinion isn't optimal. Rather than displaying item from different list why not create following interface:

```
interface IEntry
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

and then inherit it in Product and Advert adding specific functionality:

```
class Product : IEntry   
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Id { get; set; }
    DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

After that simply make class inheriting from

```
List<IEntry>
```

to make sure advert class appears the way you want.

Comment: This doesn't show how to display the adverts by AdvertView, though